# What does it mean to have one or more blkby columns in sp_who2 have the current spid in it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, blocking

For example, I am currently looking at an sp_who2 report that has about 40 lines for spid 140, about 30 of them have 140 in the blkby column.  What does this mean?  Why is there more that one row for 140, and how can the spid be blocking itself?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this when a sql server is spooling a lot of data over the pipe to a client and the client can only buffer and read  so much. So you might start to see multiple ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits. Can you post the wait type for that process using the query below:

```
SELECT 
    S.Text, R.Session_id,R.Status,R.Command,R.CPU_Time,R.Total_Elapsed_Time
FROM    
    sys.dm_exec_requests R
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS S 

--EXEC sp_who2
SELECT  W.session_id,ot.task_state,W.wait_type, W.wait_duration_ms, W.blocking_session_id, W.resource_description, S.host_name, S.program_name
FROM  
    sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks  W  
    INNER  JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks ot ON ot.task_address = W.waiting_task_address 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions S ON S.session_id = W.session_id 
WHERE 
    S.is_user_process =  1

SELECT 
    SessionID = es.session_id,
    Login =es.original_login_name,
    Host = es.host_name,
    RequestStart=es.last_request_start_time,
    RequerstEnd=es.last_request_end_time,
    Status =es.status,
    BockedBy =er.blocking_session_id,
    WaitType =er.wait_type, 
    WaitTime = er.wait_time,
    LastWaitType = er.last_wait_type,
    WaitResource = er.wait_resource,
    DatabaseID = DB_NAME(er.database_id),
    Command = er.command,
    --,sql_text=st.text
    TransactionIsolation =
        CASE es.transaction_isolation_level
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Read Uncommitted'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Read Committed'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot'
        END,
    CPUTime = COALESCE(es.cpu_time,0) + COALESCE(er.cpu_time,0),
    IOTime = COALESCE(es.reads,0) + COALESCE(es.writes,0) + COALESCE(er.reads,0) + COALESCE(er.writes,0),
    TransactioCount = COALESCE(er.open_transaction_count,-1),
    ProgramName = COALESCE(es.program_name,''),
    LoginTme = es.login_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_sessions es
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec ON es.session_id = ec.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests er ON es.session_id = er.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON es.security_id = sp.sid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks ota ON es.session_id = ota.session_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_threads oth ON ota.worker_address = oth.worker_address
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS st
WHERE 
    es.is_user_process = 1 
    and 
    es.session_id <> @@spid
ORDER BY
     es.session_id
```

Comment: At the moment the wait type is CXPACKET, but I wouldn't swear that that is the only type.

Comment: This could quite possibly be SQL buffering a large result set or working out of full buffers or to a smaller degree this could be due to parallelism, however, I doubt the latter. Are you filling up a largish temp table, does your query return a tremendous result set? This type of thing can happen when sql server worker threads produce and buffer data faster than the client can read the buffer, some of the threads must wait This article may be helpful for you --> https://www.sqlshack.com/troubleshooting-the-cxpacket-wait-type-in-sql-server/

Comment: Also, if you post this over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ then you might get a better response but be prepared to post a query plan.